# Fibonacci Numbers with Hot Potato Game

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Five people, $A, B, C, D, E$ are playing a game of Hot Potato. The potato starts with Person $A.$ Every person must pass the ball to someone else. The potato returns to person $A$ after the eighth pass. How many possible sequences of passes are there?

I think we draw a circle of the people $A,B,C,D,$ and $E.$ There are eight passes that were completed and each person has $4$ choices. Then we find the total, I'm not sure if this is the right approach, though.

Comment: Doesn't each person have $4$ choices?  What does this question have to do with Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Wrong tag, sorry. $4$ choices, oh right. Yes, you're correct.

Comment: Anyone? Please help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite right to say that everyone has $4$ choices.  Since the $8$th pass goes to $A$, the $7$th pass can't go to $A$, or $A$ would make the last pass to himself.  If we write down the players who touch the ball, in order, we'll have a $9$-letter string formed from the letters $A,B,C,D,E$ that starts and ends in $A$, such that no letter appears twice in succession, and the problem is to count these.

Suppose $A$ doesn't appear in the intermediate string (the $7$=letter string between the ends.)  Then there are $4$ choices for the first letter (anything but $A$) and $3$ choices for each succeeding letter (anything but $A$ or the preceding letter.)  That makes $4\cdot3^6$ strings with exactly $2$ $A$'s.

Now suppose there is exactly $1$ $A$ in the intermediate string.  There are $5$ places the $A$ can appear, since it can't be first or last.  We can break the $9$-letter string into two that start and end with $A$, one with $k$ letters, and one with $10-k$ letters.  (The middle $A$ is counted twice.)  By the same reasoning as above there are $\cdot3^{k-3}$ possibilities for the first string and $4\cdot3^{10-k-3}$ for the second, which gives $4^2\cdot3^4$ combinations, regardless of the value of $k$.   So, we have $5\cdot4^2\cdot3^4$ strings with exactly $3$ $A$'s.

Can you carry on?

Comment: I got $53248.$ I'm not sure though.

Comment: I didn't carry it out to completion, just showed you the way.  You could post your own answer for people to look at.

Comment: Ok, thank you :)

Comment: Wait, how many $A's$ are possible. We stop when all of them are $A's,$ right?

Comment: No, that isn't right.  You can't have two $A$'s next to one another, so there will never be more than $5$ $A$'s (including the two on the ends.)

Comment: Oh, alright. Thank you! I finished.